# Controlling a system in a particular direction

Tags: control

In Discrete-time Control Engineering by Katsuhiko Ogata, it is stated that ***"A necessary and sufficient condition for complete state controllability is that
no cancellation occurs in the pulse transfer function. If cancellation occurs, the system
cannot be controlled in the direction of the cancelled mode."***

Actually, what does controlling in a direction mean?